# dynamically change label 'for' attribute in with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each, attr

I'm trying to assign the `'for'` attribute to each label tag instead of manually typing it. In addition, I also want to make each `'for'` equal it's corresponding input `'name'`

How can I use Jquery to write code once that dynamically changes each one?

Below is my html.

I tried doing this:

```
$("input, select").each(function(){
  $(this).siblings().attr('for', [input=name].val)

});
```

but that doesn't work. Any Ideas?

```js
$("input, select").each(function(){
  $(this).siblings().attr('for', [input=name].val)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="billingArea"> 
  <p>
      <label>First Name:</label>
     <input name="billingFirstName" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Last Name:</label> 
    <input name="billingLastName" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Street Address:</label> 
    <input name="billingAddress1" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
 <label> Street Address 2: </label>
    <input name="billingAddress2" type="text" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label> City: </label>
    <input name="billingCity" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    State/Province: <select name="billingState" required />
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="Alberta, Canada">AB</option>
      <option value="Alaska, USA">AK</option>    
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Postal Code:</label> <input name="billingZip" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure you are aware, you do know that if you put the input *inside* the label, you don't need the for attribute, right?

Comment: Also `State/Province` is an odd duck not being in a label tag.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to change a bit the markup to have your inputs nested inside the label tag. This way you don't need the `for` attribute.

Although if you need to keep this markup, try this :

`var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
 $(this).siblings().attr('for', fieldName);`

```js
$("input, select").each(function(){
  var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
  $(this).siblings().attr('for', fieldName);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="billingArea"> 
  <p>
      <label>First Name:</label>
     <input name="billingFirstName" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Last Name:</label> 
    <input name="billingLastName" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Street Address:</label> 
    <input name="billingAddress1" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
 <label> Street Address 2: </label>
    <input name="billingAddress2" type="text" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label> City: </label>
    <input name="billingCity" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    State/Province: <select name="billingState" required />
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="Alberta, Canada">AB</option>
      <option value="Alaska, USA">AK</option>    
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Postal Code:</label> <input name="billingZip" type="text" value="" required />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: THIS WORKS! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add any #ids to the form controls so I added them with identical value to the [name] attribute. Instead of getting and setting attributes with jQuery methods, I use plain JavaScript because of habit. There's no real advantage of using `.attr()` over `.set/getAttribute()` or vice versa. If you still want a jQuery version, there is the jQuery equivalent commented within the **Demo**. Do not mix them up if you are not comfortable [dereferencing jQuery Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533784/2813224), use one or the other.

**Note:** This particular statement:

```
var field = $(this)[0].nextElementSibling;
```

The bracket notation with zero index **(`[0]`)** dereferences the jQuery Object **(`$("selector")`)** into a plain JavaScript Object **(`selector`)**. The reason for dereferencing a jQuery Object is usually so a plain JavaScript property or method can be used. A jQuery methods does not recognize plain JavaScript Objects and that goes for plain JavaScript methods toward jQuery Objects as well.

### Demo

**Details are commented within the Demo**

```js
/* each() <label>...
|| Get <label>'s sibling element that folloows it.
|| Get that sibling's #id
|| Set the <label>'s [for] attribute value to the sibling's #id
*/
$('label').each(function(i, L) {

  //var field = $(this).next();
  var field = $(this)[0].nextElementSibling;

  //var ID = field.attr('id');
  var ID = field.id;

  //$(this).attr('for', ID);
  this.setAttribute('for', ID);
});
```

```css
label,
select,
innput {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  width: 15ch
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 45ch
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 12ch;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<form id="billingArea">
  <fieldset>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input id="billingFirstName" name="billingFirstName" type="text" value="" required />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input id="billingLastName" name="billingLastName" type="text" value="" required />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Street Address:</label>
    <input id="billingAddress1" name="billingAddress1" type="text" value="" required />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label> Street Address 2: </label>
    <input id="billingAddress2" name="billingAddress2" type="text" value="" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label> City: </label>
    <input id="billingCity" name="billingCity" type="text" value="" required />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>State/Province: </label><select id="billingState" name="billingState" required>
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="Alberta, Canada">AB</option>
      <option value="Alaska, USA">AK</option>    
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Postal Code:</label> <input id="billingZip" name="billingZip" type="number" value="" required min='10000' max='99999' />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```