# How to highlight specific values on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, on a site like [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/?category=2d)

How can I code something that will highlight any prices above €20 red within the product grid? Also, I need it to continue to work even when users select/deselect categories on the right.

Would this be JavaScript?

```
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.mErEH _223RA').sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.innerText - a.innerText;
  }).slice(0, 5).addClass('higherthan20')
});
```

```
.higherthan20 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything not working with the given code? I struggle to see where you compare the actual prices to the 20 euro

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to element using its classList properties

```js
element.classList.add("higherthan20");
```

Your code would now be something like this:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.mErEH _223RA').sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.innerText - a.innerText;
  }).slice(0, 5).forEach((element) => element.classList.add('higherthan20'))
});
```

If you want to conditionally add color to text, your code can become like this:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.mErEH _223RA').sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.innerText - a.innerText;
  }).slice(0, 5).forEach((element) => {
 if (element.innerText === "20") {
    element.color = 'red'
 }
 // or other text
 // you can try using regex to match string that you need
 
});
```

Comment: thanks. Actually, what if i was to skip over adding classes and just change the element to be color: red; ?

Comment: For that you can do ```style.backgroundColor = 'red' // or color='red' for text color```

Comment: im terribly sorry, im missing closing )) now. How would my code look after using style.Color = 'red' ? On this page https://rb.gy/tm5at im basically trying to run a script that is essentially - if value is greater than = 20  { return style.backgroundColor = 'red'

Comment: I've added an edit for your color change base on condition

Comment: thank you. although its throwing up a Unexpected token 'if' error

Comment: I just fix the syntax error. I think it's now correct

Answer (score 0):

The [site](https://assetstore.unity.com/) referenced, filters prices by displaying only prices that meet a range defined by the user while removing any prices not within the price range. The filter you requested just highlights anything more than 20. Moreover, the second request:

> *"Also, I need it to continue to work even when users select/deselect categories on the right."*,

is impossible to answer since you haven't posted any code involving any of the other filters.

Concerning the code that was posted, it fails not only syntactically, but in purpose as well.

1. jQuery methods do not recognize plain JavaScript references and vice versa. In order to use a plain JavaScript method on a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), the jQuery object must be [dereferenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5533773/2813224). Avoid chaining jQuery and JavaScript methods. Below is a table of jQuery methods and a table of plain JavaScript methods used in the question:

   - **jQuery Methods**

     | Method | Description |
     | --- | --- |
     | ``` .each() ``` | iterates over a jQuery object and calls a function for each DOM element |
     | ``` .find() ``` | collects all specified DOM elements within a jQuery object as a new jQuery object |
     | ``` .addClass() ``` | adds a class(es) to each DOM element within a jQuery object |
   - **Plain JavaScript Methods**

     | Method | Description |
     | --- | --- |
     | ``` .sort() ``` | returns a new copy of a given array in ascending order |
     | ``` .slice() ``` | returns a defined range of elements within a given array as a new array |
2. In short, the jQuery object consisting of all `div.mErEH _223RA` is created by `.each()` and `.find()`. Then the function fails when `.sort()` is called on said jQuery object because:

   - `.sort()` is a plain JavaScript method which does not recognize jQuery objects
   - `.sort()` deals with arrays, of which jQuery objects are not
3. If the function were to forgo jQuery all together and just collect all `div.mErEH _223RA` as a NodeList and then convert into an array, `.sort()` and `.slice()` will work. Unfortunately, a new array that consists of the first 6 DOM elements in ascending order is returned which is not even close to highlighting all DOM elements with over 20.

In the following example, the actual HTML layout is irrelevant, the className `".x"` should be replaced with `".mErEH _223RA"`.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/**
 * For each ".x"...
 */
$(".x").each(function() {
  /**
   * ...get it's text with .textContent.
   * Then exclude the first character ("€") with .substring(1)...
   * ...and convert the text into a real number with Number().
   */
  let price = Number(this.textContent.substring(1));
  /**
   * Next, if the number is greater than 20...
   */
  if (price > 20) {
    /**
     * ...add ".red" className to DOM element. 
     */
    $(this).addClass("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td class="x">€20</td><td class="x">€100</td><td class="x">€10</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="x">€55</td><td class="x">€2</td><td class="x">€2000</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="x">€8</td><td class="x">€325</td><td class="x">€120</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="x">€70</td><td class="x">€99</td><td class="x">€220</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="x">€19</td><td class="x">€25</td><td class="x">€440</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="x">€111</td><td class="x">€44</td><td class="x">€13</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```